# Spring boot: inject mock into Runner class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have a spring boot application and some other components which application should interact with. However, in my unit testing I am using just application functionality and I would like to mock outer API calls. I am stuck as I can't find the way to mock case like this:

My start class with main method:

```
@ComponentScan("com.sample.application")
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private OuterAPI outerAPI;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(AdRedirectorMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        outerAPI.createInstances();
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is my test class example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
public class MyAppTest {
    // any tests
}
```

I am working with Spring Boot, JUnit, Mockito.

So, I am facing the problem - how could I avoid this method call createInstances() with Mockito, via reflection or in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Mocking and spying beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) in the Spring Boot documentation.

You can use `@MockBean` in your test class to replace an autowired bean with a Mockito mock instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@MockBean` http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

or you can define an interface that you OuterAPI implements then for your test you provide a dummy implementation that makes a dummy call instead of actual call to the `outerAPI.createInstances();`

Another option that you have is to have configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(value = {"yourtest-profile"})
public class TestConfiguration{

@Primary
    @Bean
    public OuterAPI outerAPI() {
        return Mockito.mock(OuterAPI.class);
    }

}
```

and put it under scr/test/java